# What are the sequence of events when loading xhr data into a react redux routed page?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, axios

I'm a react/redux noob, and am getting myself confused.

**Here's what I want to achieve:**

/myapp/#/

- global navigation with links to /myapp/#/ and /myapp/#/products

/myapp/#/products

- global navigation (as above)
- list of products retrieved from axios GET XHR request. Each product links to /myapp/#/products/{productId}

/myapp/#/products/{productId}

- global navigation (as above)
- list of products (as above)
- product details panel which shows additional details retrieved from another axios GET XHR request

User should be able to click products in the list to view details in the inset product details panel, but the list XHR request should not be re-requested.

**My Code**

/index.js

```
    ...
    //I don't think this is the right place for this code...
    function loadProductListData() {
        store.dispatch(fetchListData('/api/products'))
    }

    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
                <Route path="/products(/:productId)" component={ProductsPage} onEnter={loadProductListData} />
            </Router>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
    ...
```

/components/menu.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'react-router';

    const Menu = () => (
        <ul>
            <li><Link to={''}>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'products'}>Products</Link></li>
        </ul>
    )

    export default Menu
```

/components/productList.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'react-router';

    class List extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.props.products.map(product =>
                            this.renderRow(product)
                        )
                    }
                </ul>
            )
        }

        renderRow (product) {
            return (
                <li key={product.id}><Link to={'products/' + product.id}>{product.name}</Link></li>
            )
        }
    }

    export default List
```

/actions.js

```
    export const REQ_DATA = 'REQ_DATA';
    export const RECV_DATA = 'RECV_DATA';
    import axios from 'axios'

    function requestData() {
        return {type: types.REQ_DATA}
    }

    function receiveData(json) {
        return{
            type: types.RECV_DATA,
            data: json
        }
    }

    export function fetchListData(url) {
        return function(dispatch) {
            dispatch(requestData())
            return axios({
                url: url,
                timeout: 20000,
                method: 'get',
                responseType: 'json'
            })
                .then(function(response) {
                    dispatch(receiveData(response.data))
                })
                .catch(function(response){
                    //
                })
        }
    }
```

My code above works, but I'm now in a tangle about what to do next. I'm not sure I should be using onEnter on the route to trigger the XHR request because the link to the product details page goes through the same route, and fires the same XHR for list data.

**My Question**
Instead of using Link, should I use an onClick handler which fires the XHR, updates state (causing component re-render), and then push to a new route manually? Is it correct for the link to simply re-route, and possible for everything else to be triggered as a result of the routing? As I say, I don't want to re-load the list component when re-routing.

Any other general advice on approach and architecture for an application like this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather dispatch the loadList action within componentWillMount() and implement a shouldComponentUpdate callback within your List component to control wether the component should be rendered/updated again or not - based on your state.

So for instance:

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
       return this.props.products !== nextProps.products;
    }
```

Check the docs at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Then use "301 - Not Modified" headers on your backend to not always return the same data if nothing has been changed within your products list.

For loading the product detail you could dispatch your detail loading action within componentWillReceiveProps like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.params.id !== nextProps.params.id) {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchDetailProduct(nextProps.params.id));
  }
}
```

This way you are checking if the user clicked on a different product id. If so, the action to load this detail data is dispatched. The component will be updated with your new product detail data based on your redux flow.

As an architectural advice, i would also suggest you to give your actions better names like 'PRODUCT/FETCH_LIST', 'PRODUCT/FETCH_LIST_RECEIVED', 'PRODUCT/FETCH_LIST_ERROR'.

I'd also suggest using Immutable.js (https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js) for your state. It will be much easier to identify updates within your state, since it provides some efficient equals() checks for all the objects. With an Immutable.js data structure, your shouldComponentUpdate will look like this:

```
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
       return !this.props.products.equals(nextProps.products);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will digest asap, and let you know.

Comment: OK, so the PRODUCT/FETCH_LIST action makes the GET /api/products list XHR, and is invoked with componentWillMount() within the product list component (/container). When a user clicks a product from the list, should I still use the <Link> component, to re-route to /products/{productId}? And then use componentWillMount() within the productDetails component to invoke a PRODUCT/FETCH_DETAILS action which makes the GET /api/products/{productId} XHR. But what happens when the user clicks another product? The productDetails component is already mounted. Is there a different callback I should use?

Comment: Each container component (ProductList, ProductDetail) should have their own route handler and within componentWillMount you are dispatching your action to load its contents. You should definitely not load your data based on the url. If a user clicks on another Product the Detail component should be mounted again with different params identifying the product that has been clicked. You can also use componentWillReceiveProps to reload the data for a different product detail. I edited my answer to match this.

Comment: Thanks again @denis-s. I'll have had good success so far with the list using  componentWillMount to load the list data. I'll have a go tomorrow with componentWillReceiveProps for the detail component, along with it's own route handler. I'll let you know how I get on. :)

Comment: Actually, one area I'd still like to clarify - I've got one 'page' which renders two 'panels': the list view; and the details view (if one of the list items is selected). At the moment, I've got a single 'ListAndDetailsPage' (which is the component rendered by the route), 'ListContainer', 'ListComponent, 'DetailsContainer', 'DetailsComponent'. To my mind it's all one 'page' with an optional details panel. I bow to your superior judgement, but I'm slightly surprised that details would have it's own route given that the entire DOM structure is the same other than the additional details panel.

Comment: Details should always have their own url since you want the user to copy and paste the url to this specific page. You can make use of the :param syntax to even automatically pass the id of that detail item to your components params, so :productID is available as this.props.params.productID.